# Different Name for user in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am running SP Foundation and have users in the site through AD groups. Some of the users are complaining to have incorrect Names showing up in the SP Site when they login.

I dont have user profile sync service, but want to have my AD user accounts to get updated in SP site in an automated way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 Change your display of welcome name Sync to Active Directory check this link

http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2011/06/22/sharepoint-2010-change-your-display-of-wellcome-name/